# pandas - Convert bool object to bool primitive in a column

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

The `df` has a column named `isInDST` which is a bool object type.

```
df.isInDST

0          True
1          True
2          True
3          True
4          True
5          True
6          True
7          True
8          True
9          True
...         ...  
849350    False
849351    False
849352    False
849353    False
849354    False
849355    False
849356    False
849357    False
849358    False
849359    False
Name: isInDST, Length: 849360, dtype: object
```

This `isInDST` column was created from a map function:

```
df['isInDST'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Australia/Victoria').map(lambda x : bool(x.dst().total_seconds()!=0))
```

I think my question is how to edit the map function to make `isInDST` become a `bool` primitive type rather than `object`?

Comment: `df['isInDST'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time']) !=0`?

Comment: or just `df['isInDST'] = df['isInDST'].astype(bool)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fix your problem

```
df['isInDST'] = df['isInDST'].astype('bool')
```

Update

```
df['isInDST'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Australia/Victoria').map(lambda x : x.dst().total_seconds()!=0)
```

Comment: Can we edit the map function to achieve this?

Comment: @alextc remove  the bool ~

Comment: This still generated the bool object.

Comment: @alextc without seeing the the data the easy fix will be `df['isInDST'] = df['isInDST'].astype('bool')
`

Comment: I am happy to accept it. However further to this post are you able to help with another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66995959/pandas-how-to-improve-performance-on-a-lambda-function-on-a-massive-dataframe