# How to improve performance on a lambda function on a massive dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `df` with over hundreds of millions of rows.

```
     latitude                    longitude                   time                    VAL     
0   -39.20000076293945312500    140.80000305175781250000    1972-01-19 13:00:00     1.20000004768371582031  
1   -39.20000076293945312500    140.80000305175781250000    1972-01-20 13:00:00     0.89999997615814208984 
2   -39.20000076293945312500    140.80000305175781250000    1972-01-21 13:00:00     1.50000000000000000000 
3   -39.20000076293945312500    140.80000305175781250000    1972-01-22 13:00:00     1.60000002384185791016 
4   -39.20000076293945312500    140.80000305175781250000    1972-01-23 13:00:00     1.20000004768371582031
... ...
```

It contains a `time` column with the type of `datetime64` in UTC. The following code is to create a new column `isInDST` to indicate if the `time` is in daylight saving period in a local time zone.

```
df['isInDST'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Australia/Victoria').map(lambda x : x.dst().total_seconds()!=0)
```

It takes about 400 seconds to process 15,223,160 rows.

Is there a better approach to achieve this with better performance? Is `vectorize` a better way?

Comment: Can you try using `df['isInDST'] = [x.dst().total_seconds()!=0 for x in pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Australia/Victoria')]`

Comment: Thanks @AmitVikramSingh. Your code took 810 seconds to process 103,621,920 rows. I have 148*244*424680 = 15,336,044,160 records. Given this is a linear processing it would take more than 30 hours to process the whole data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467759/flag-daylight-saving-time-dst-hours-in-pandas-date-time-column

Comment: maybe something using `utcoffset()` could be slightly faster?

Comment: How about comparing `df['time'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Australia/Victoria').map(pd.Timestamp.dst) > datetime.timedelta()` ?

Answer (score 2):

*All results are calculated on 1M datapoints.*

### Cython + `np.vectorize`

7.2 times faster than the original code

```
%%cython
from cpython.datetime cimport datetime
cpdef bint c_is_in_dst(datetime dt):
    return dt.dst().total_seconds() != 0 

%%timeit
df['isInDST'] = np.vectorize(c_is_in_dst)(df['time'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Australia/Victoria').dt.to_pydatetime())
```

*1.08 s ± 10.2 ms per loop per loop*

### `np.vectorize`

6.5 times faster than the original code

```
def is_in_dst(dt):
    return dt.dst().total_seconds() != 0 

%%timeit
df['isInDST'] = np.vectorize(is_in_dst)(df['time'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Australia/Victoria').dt.to_pydatetime())
```

*1.2 s ± 29.3 ms per loop per loop*

Based on the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) (`The implementation is essentially a for loop`) I expected the result to be the same as for the list comprehension, but it's consistently a little bit better than list comprehension.

### List comprehension

5.9 times faster than the original code

```
%%timeit
df['isInDST'] = [x.dst().total_seconds()!=0 for x in pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Australia/Victoria')]
```

*1.33 s ± 48.4 ms per loop*

This result shows that pandas `map`/`apply` is very slow, it adds additional overhead that can be eliminated by just using a python for loop.

### Original approach (`map` on pandas DatetimeIndex)

```
%%timeit
df['isInDST'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Australia/Victoria').map(lambda x : x.dst().total_seconds()!=0)
```

*7.82 s ± 84.3 ms per loop*

Tested on 1M rows of dummy data

```
N = 1_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({"time": [datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=random.randint(0,23),minute=random.randint(0,59)) for _ in range(N)]})
```

Also, run the code on 100K and 10M rows - the results are linearly dependant on the number of rows